# Data filtration from JSONB | Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a question regarding querying data from jsob fields.

I have a following table (simplified):

```sql
create table mytable
(
   
    headers          jsonb                    not null,
    
);
```

`headers` column stores HTTP headers, one of them is "`PATH_INFO`" ( always present in data) and it basically stores related paths of requests.

Example `"/api/users"`

What is the best way to get all unique `"PATH_INFO"` entries from `headers` data keeping in mind that path with `/` at the end and without `/` at the end should be treated as same paths?

Example  - `"/api/users" == "/api/users/"`

LIKE and ILIKE seem to slow…

Thank you.

Postgres version - 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to 'normalize' PATH_INFO (i.e. remove the trailing slash if any) using `regexp_replace` like this.

```sql
select distinct regexp_replace(headers->>'PATH_INFO', '/?$', '')
from mytable;
```